# 中【ちゅう】? 中【じゅう】? 中【ぢゅう】? 中【なか】?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

まだ薄暗【うすぐら】い中【?】、子【こ】どもたちが集【あつ】まってきた

*It was still dimly lit, but the children had gathered.*

https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/279297

Here (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41086/31150) it says...

*Since it is an individual word, it should be pronounced as なか.
じゅう(or ちゅう) is used only when 中 is an affix (attached to a noun).*

In the FNN sentence above, the 薄暗【うすぐら】い looks like an attributive adjective modfiying 中 , which suggests that it should be pronounced as なか ... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is なか. Slightly more generally, adjective + 中 meaning *in the middle of adj.* is read なか as far as I can think of. E.g. 忙しい[中]{なか}, 天気の悪い[中]{なか}.

More generally, there is probably no clear rules, i.e., it depends on words whether it is ちゅう or じゅう or なか (じゅう and ぢゅう are not distinguished in modern Japanese).

---

A basic difference is that なか/ちゅう means *in the middle of* while じゅう means *throughout, all over (some range)*, but not entirely correct. For example, 午前[中]{ちゅう} can mean both (午前中誰か来た/午前中はいません). A further complication is 午前[中]{ちゅう}[中]{じゅう} is possible at least colloquially (maybe a bit odd, but definitely understood). Also, 午後[中]{じゅう} is the only possibility which means *throughout the afternoon*. *Some time in the afternoon* is simply 午後 and never 午後[中]{ちゅう}.

Some more examples: [海中]{かいちゅう} = inside the sea; [海中]{うみじゅう} = all over the sea (as far as can be seen); [山中]{やまなか} = [山中]{さんちゅう} = (somewhere) inside the mountain; [山中]{やまじゅう} = all over the mountain.

---

Relevant threads on or off this SE.

- [中(なか) vs 中(ちゅう)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B-vs-%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A1%E3%82%85%E3%81%86)
- [How do we decide if 中 is ちゅう or じゅう?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2790/45489)
- [~中（ちゅう・じゅう）](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/chuju/)
- [中（ちゅう）と中（じゅう）の違いは？](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3537032.html)